# Syncing of calendar with iCloud causes duplication of events

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, icloud

We are developing a calendar app, in which the events can be created/deleted/updated by the user. The events needs to be synced with the native and iCloud calendar. When the events created in the app is synced with the native calendar we do not see any duplication of events. However when the events are synced with iCloud calendar we some time get duplication.

On analysing we observed that multiple identifiers are returned by the calendar in this case.

We went through the below links and not much information is available with respect to event duplication. Any input/suggestion on this will be helpful.

[iCloud calendar synchronization issue while creating calendar from application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623782/icloud-calendar-synchronization-issue-while-creating-calendar-from-application)

[Syncing of Calendar with iCloud lose the CalendarIdentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352163/syncing-of-calendar-with-icloud-lose-the-calendaridentifier)

Answer (score 0):

When multiple identifiers are returned for the same calendar name, then we tried to delete all the calendar with the same name present in the cloud. Then tried to create a fresh calendar and sync the date. In this approach we can avoid events getting duplication. However duplicate events will be seen for a moment till the sync operation gets completed.